# Python: Visualize a normal curve on data's histogram

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks in advance for any assistance or tips.

I'm trying to visualize the fitted normal to one of my dataframe's column. So far, I've been able to plot the histogram by:

```
df.radon_adj.hist(bins=30)
```

[image: hist]

I've this '[template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779316/un-normalized-gaussian-curve-on-histogram)', but I encounter errors.

```
import pylab as py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

# Generate a 
y = df.radon_adj
data = py.hist(y, bins = 25)

# Equation for Gaussian
def f(x, a, b, c):
    return a * py.exp(-(x - b)**2.0 / (2 * c**2))

# Generate data from bins as a set of points 
x = [0.5 * (data[1][i] + data[1][i+1]) for i in xrange(len(data[1])-1)]
y = data[0]

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(f, x, y)

x_fit = py.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 100)
y_fit = f(x_fit, *popt)

plot(x_fit, y_fit, lw=4, color="r")
```

Comment: Some example data would be useful here- we can't actually run your example code without it. Try to mock up a small example dataset that we can copy-paste (`np.random.randn()` is very useful for generating random data).

Comment: Have you tried to run this example from Matplotlib? http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_features.html

Comment: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/plotting_distributions.html I will seaborn the plot out of it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel by defining the equation for Gaussian. Stand on the shoulders of the scipy package:

```
from scipy.stats import norm  
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.normal(size=100)})

df.A.plot(kind='hist', normed=True)

range = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.001)
plt.plot(range, norm.pdf(range,0,1))
```

[image]

Note that the only 'magic' here is making sure the histogram is normed.

Comment: In `pandas v0.23.3` the `normed` kwarg is deprecated and has been replaced by the `density` kwarg use  `df.A.plot(kind='hist', density=True)`