# Draw a Bell Curve on my Distribution Sample

Tags: python, apache-spark, matplotlib, gaussian, bell-curve

I have the following piece of code:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
dfPy = sqlContext.table("df")

pd = dfPy.toPandas()

pd[['col4']].plot(kind='hist', bins=[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100], rwidth=0.8)
plt.show()
```

And I get to see the following result of running it in the Apache Zeppelin notebook:

[image: Bell Curve]

As it can be seen that I have two issues:

1. How can I draw a bell curve? Seems the distribution is not normal or gaussian like. So I suppose that I should do some data transformation. Correct?
2. How can I now draw a bell curve on the resulting histogram?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area so I don't know if the answers I'm about to present will help you. You can find the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115531/python-visualize-a-normal-curve-on-datas-histogram).

Comment: I came across that post and I might give it a try.